# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'lambda expression'

Tags: c#, operators

I'm getting this error `Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands type 'bool' and 'lambda expression'`
 I'm struggling with this

```
if ((counter <= value1) || (counter => value2))
{
// Do something
}
```

Can you please help me out.

Comment: use `counter >= value2`

Comment: thanks guys, feel awkward that I was only stuck by something so small

Comment: Mods, your reason for closing this topic is flawed.  This was not a typographical error.  This was a misunderstanding of the way the operators worked, and it *IS* in fact likely to help future readers.  A typographical error would be if the author had intended to write it the correct way, but mistakenly written it the other way.  This was not the case.  As such, the question does "fit the rules", but many people seem to misunderstand the rules.  Voting to re-open.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - I understand your point, but I fear that as the question is posted - it is not very discoverable to people with a _similar_ (but not _identical_) problem...

Comment: @UriAgassi - Considering that the subject is essentially the error message, and I tried several different variations that all resulted with this answer as the top result, I think you are wrong about that.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - in that case, I vote to re-open

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s `>=` (said “greater than or equal to” after all), not `=>`. `=>` creates [a lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) – in this case, one that takes an argument called `counter` and always returns `value2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I'll never forget